# LWC LMS: Invalid message context error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I ask this question because I did not find any similar.

My error is "invalid message context". I will explain it graphically.

From tab 1, I create a record, with a navigation mixin, I am automatically redirected to tab 2.

In tab 2 I have two main components, the header and the parent, the parent contains two children.

I am using channel message to communicate the components. When I click the "button" in the header, it publish a message, the parent receives it and makes some api calls. Then, at the end of the calls, the parent publishes a message for the children to perform other actions.

The first time I do this, it works great. But when I close tab 2, I go back to tab 1 and do exactly the same process, this time when I click the "button" in the header, it shows me the "Invalid message context" error and nothing works.

But if before doing the second round, I press F5, everything works fine. In my opinion, this happens because a channel message is being saved, the messages are not deleted before the second round.

**How can I clean all the channel messages when I close tab 2? I am not using the "unsubscribe" method, nor the "releaseMessageContext" method. Should I use that? If the answer is "Yes", where should I use that? In the disconnectedCallback?**

Thank you very much...

[image]

Comment: I doubt that there is any generic problem with LMS which could cause this issue. For further troubleshooting, are you able to update the question with relevant code snippets?

Comment: I was able to solve it by applying another alternative. Instead of publishing a MessageChannel to the children, what I did was fire the children's events from the parent to send data. But i didn't find the solution of "Invalid message context" in the second round. Handling a lot of channel messages can be confusing for me. Thank you!